# In java Regex, How can I get a certain part of a fileName

Tags: java, regex

I have a String which is basically a file name. I need to retrieve a certain
part of the file name. It is the value before second - (dash). Filenames will be in format example:

**fileName-014qsqs-xxxxyyyzzz.txt**

I need to get as a result:

**fileName-014qsqs**

How can I use regex to it?

Thanks

Comment: So what do you want to extract in your example, `014qsqs`? What did you try so far? And does it have to be a regex or would splitting the filename at dashes be ok as well?

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use a regex for this? Regular expressions are not a golden hammer for any task that has to do with strings, and a simple `indexOf` and `substring` will do the job here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: No actually I need everything before the second dash. In this case, I need to have as a result "fileName-014qsqs"

Answer (score 2):

When trying to figure this out, it can be helpful to use a regex tester (e.g. http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

The regex `(.*?-.*?)-.*` matches what you are looking for.

`.*`: Any character any number of times

`?`: Makes it non-greedy, so it only does as few as possible to match

`-`: Literal dash

`()`:  The parentheses make it a group so it can be extracted.

The entire program looks like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String atrgs[])
    {
        String line = "fileName-014qsqs-xxxxyyyzzz.txt";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?-.*?)-.*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

And has the output `fileName-014qsqs`.

Comment: Have you crosschecked this with filenames containing more than 2 dashes?

Comment: Thanks this really helps but I need everything before the second "-". In this case it will be "fileName-014qsqs"

Comment: @SebastianProske No. OP, is supporting >2 dashes req'd?

Comment: @Daniel Centore, much better, thanks ;-) But what if my file has more than 2 dashes, like  : fileName-05-abc-def-zzz-yyy. Here, I only need :  fileName-05

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression:

```
"([^-]*-[^-]*)-.*"
```

Explanation: any character but "-" is expressed as "[^-]" hence the

```
([^-]*-[^-]*)
```

captures a sequence of non-"-" characters separated by a single "-", next a second "-" followed by any further text.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i probably do a while and when find the 2 "-" stop.Sry can't comment